# Laravel - Mailcatcher shows a 'This site can’t be reached' page

Tags: laravel, mailcatcher

I've just installed Mailcatcher for a Laravel project I'm working on, and I'm using Virtual Box and Vagrant to run the application locally. When I run the command `mailcatcher` on my terminal I get:

```
Starting MailCatcher
==> smtp://127.0.0.1:1025
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/server.rb:104: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
==> http://127.0.0.1:1080
*** MailCatcher runs as a daemon by default. Go to the web interface to quit.
```

But when I visit http://127.0.0.1:1080 I get the following page:

[image]

My app is running on the IP 192.168.10.10 so I also tried using that, but the same result. I'm not entirely sure if it's something to do with my localhost or Mailcatcher, but in an ideal world I'd like to run it off a URL like this: `192.168.10.10/mailcatcher` but I'm unsure how to set this up in my project. If I can just get the localhost to work I'd be happy - is there any other settings I need to change in order to make this work? Or is it that my localhost is not playing ball?

**EDIT:**

In case it's needed, my .env file in my Laravel project has the following settings for mail:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_PRETEND=false
```

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same issue, this worked for me.

`mailcatcher --foreground`.